# How can I pass data between two React components, but the two components have no parent-child relationship?

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, react-props, react-context

For example, I have data in a component which is inside **"components"** folder. Now I want to use the data in an another component which is inside **"views"** folder. So far I know, Context API will not work here.
So how can I pass data in this scenario? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: *"Context API will not work here"* - Why not?  If the components have no known-ahead-of-time parent/child relationship then there's one universal parent/child relationship that all components share... They're all children of `<App/>`.  Maybe the context just needs to be defined at the top level and both of the components access it?

Comment: Mr. @David , Sorry. I have very poor knowledge in react js. Would you like to clear little bit more, please? It would be very helpful for me.

Comment: @GcrMusadul You could make a context in a file, and export it. In both of your other files where you need to use it, you would just import it.

Comment: I think you can either use ContextAPI with High Order Component and wrap your main <App/> component with it. Or you can use localStorage for sharing data between component. And last but not least you can even use Redux for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Redux by maintaining the states of all child components that you might need in a global store and obtain the data from said store.

https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

make sure to use redux toolkit to simplify your setup:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I know two solutions to this.

---

The first and preferred one is to pass a exported function of one component as a property to the other component and thus linking them together, like:

```
import Dispay from './components/Dispay.js'
import Input from './views/Input.js'

<Input pushData={Dispay.pullData}/>
<Dispay/>
```

Here a working example of this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-between-unrelated-components-rr2li?file=/src/App.js

---

The second method is an easy, although a bit dirty solution.
Use the browsers window object, as all React components can access this object.
In practice this might look like this:

**Syncronous (event based):**

components/MainComponent.js:

```
// call the other component's method with some data
window.processData("myDataString")
```

views/Element.js:

```
window.processData = function(data) {
    // do something with your data like
    console.log("MainComponent received data:",data);
}
```

**Asyncronously**

```
//read and write to this object from wherever you like
window.data
```