# Passing data between two React components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch, tsx

I have a React component in which I receive data. But I want to use this data in another component as well. What is the best way to do this? I don't want to use the child parent method like in the React documentation. What is the best way to do this?

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/login")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
       });
```

In this component I am getting the data and I want to use it in the next component

```
import React from 'react'

function test() {
  return (
    <div>test</div>
  )
}

export default test
```

In addition I don't want to use the localstorge of the browser because of safety reasons

I want to transfer the data and I don't want to have any tags in the return section.

Comment: "I don't want to use the child parent method like in the React documentation". It sounds like you shouldn't be using React then. Parent/child component relationships are a fundamental concept of React

Comment: I know. Normaly I do it in this way but this time i dont want to display the child in the parent component. I only want the data like with an localstorge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass data between two React components, but the two components have no parent-child relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464217/how-can-i-pass-data-between-two-react-components-but-the-two-components-have-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods for what you want to achieve, but with no doubt the best one, particularly in this situation, is using **props**.

You can use props to transfer data from parent to child component like this:

in Parent.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

function Parent() {
    const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState();

    return (
        <div>
            <Child data={loginData} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

in Child.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

function Child(props: { data: any }) {
    return <p>props.data</p>
}

export default Child
```

**Props** is a really important concept to learn as a react developer, since they are the fundamental of communication between parent and child components.

Another way to pass data from a component to another is using **Context**, but it's slightly more advanced and it's usually used for global data.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one component to another through **3** ways:-

1. By passing data as a prop. **One way***(Only from parent component to child)*
2. By using useContext Hook. **Both way**(From parent to child and child to parent)
3. User react-redux. ***(Accessible over all routes)*** same as 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **React Context API**, **Redux**, or **Mobx**. Redux is recommended for large projects, while Mobx is useful and easy to use for simpler operations.